# Retrieve image from mysql and set to pictureBox C#

Tags: c#, mysql, image, picturebox, system.drawing.imaging

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database and set it to textbox and picture box using text change.

Here is my code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlstring = "database = db_phonebook; user = root; password = ''; server = 'localhost'; SSL Mode = None";
        MySqlConnection mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(sqlstring);
        MySqlCommand mysqlcom;
        MySqlDataReader mdr;

        mysqlcon.Open();

        string selectquery = ("SELECT* FROM tbl_phonebook WHERE CID LIKE '" + this.textBox1.Text + "%'");
        mysqlcom = new MySqlCommand(selectquery, mysqlcon);

        mdr = mysqlcom.ExecuteReader();

    if (mdr.Read())
        {
            cid.Text = mdr.GetString("CID");
            name.Text = mdr.GetString("Name");
            address.Text = mdr.GetString("Address");
            contact.Text = mdr.GetString("Contact_Number");
            email.Text = mdr.GetString("Email_Address");
            photobox.Image = mdr.("Photo"); /// this line is the error it says "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Imaging'
        }
    else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Not Found!");
        }

        mysqlcon.Close();
    }
```

how do I fix "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Imaging' or is there another way to display image from database in picture box

Comment: What is the data type for your Photo column in your tbl_phonebook table?

Comment: Please consider using parameterization for your query since building a string from a textbox input could result in SQL Injection https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: There are *many* dozens of posts already here wonderfully illustrating how to convert from blob to image.

Comment: @DCAggie photo data type is varchar

Comment: Can you share an example of a value? Are they URLs or something?

Comment: @DCAggie it returns the file name of image I selected example: picture.jpg

Comment: So you're trying to do this - `photobox.Image = "picture.jpg"`?

Comment: Man with your query you will be come under sql injection attack

Comment: Are your image type is blob ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `photobox` object is a `PictureBox` and that your database stores a link or path to your image, instead of setting the .Image property call its Load method which will set the Image location and load it:

```
photobox.Load(mdr.GetString("Photo"));
```

Comment: Read more about the Load() method here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.load?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: I've tried photobox.Load(mdr.("Photo")); but it says it should have an identifier

Comment: Can you provide an exception message/stack trace?

Comment: Have you verified that there is a file named picture.jpg in your application's working directory?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `GetString`